# Intellij long "integer value is too big" but in range of long.maxvalue

Tags: intellij-idea, javac, long-integer

[image: Integer number too large error]

This might be a silly thing but how is this possible that compiler will show this while `Long.Max = 9223372036854775807` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must have `Long` literals in Java ending with an `L`, adding an `L` to your integer will correct your issue, like so: `Long s = 9223372036854775806L`

This is because by default Java interprets all integers as 32-bit (`int`), the suffix `L` ensures that your integer is interpreted as 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

just put 'l' or 'L' in the end of it and it will be ok, like:

```
long a = 9223372036854775807L;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Long s = 9223372036854775806L`